# differentiating between the usages of "so that" and "so...that"

Tags: vocabulary, adverbs, conjunctions

I have written these. Would anyone possibly correct me? and if the two mean the same thing?

**So, A shows the result, whereas B shows both the degree and the result. –**

And, eventually are the sentences correct both?

> 1. After using modern machines to harvest crops, the speed of harvesting, coupled with the quality of the crops, **increased, so that the income** from selling crops at once manyfolded as well as taking full advantage of crops improved as quickly as possible.

and

> 2. After using modern machines to harvest crops, the speed of harvesting, coupled with the quality of the crops, **increased so high that the income** from selling crops at once manyfolded as well as taking full advantage of crops improved as quickly as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question title and the question itself are not quite the same. Are you looking for differences, or corrections? Also, in your second example you probably want 'much', not 'high'.

Answer (score 1):

*X so that Y* means X happened, and that fact allowed Y to exist or happen.  Without X happening, Y would not happen.

In *X so Y [that] Z* (*that* will often be omitted):

- X will be a noun or pronoun,
- Y will be a predicate (including a verb) that expresses a degree or level of a quality or state or becoming a quality or state,
- Z is what did happen when, or could happen if, something was able to change X to Y.

Another way to express it is *Z because X so Y*.

> He made me so breathless that I almost fainted.  (I almost fainted because he made me so breathless.)
>
> The water is so clear that I can see my feet.  (I saw my feet because the water was so clear.)

Comment: I think the second bit about "so y that z" is off. If Y is an adverb, then X can be a verb, rather than a noun: "I ran so quickly (that) my shoes fell off". Since the asker's example refers to increasing, "increased so high" is synonymous with "increased so much" (although it's not the best wording), and 'high' is acting as an adverb modifying 'increased'. Other than that, I think you've pretty much got it.

Comment: Also, could probably emphasize that in the XYZ phrasing, the simple fact that X *happened* is not enough to have caused Z, it needed to happen in this certain *way*.

Comment: So, A shows the result, whereas B shows both the degree and the result.